# How should I be storing one to many collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

*Not sure if collection is the right word but I'm trying to say whatever a table would be in MongoDB*

I'm planning on making a switch from MySQL to MongoDB and have been reading up on it but one thing I can't seem to find much coverage on is one-to-many or many-to-many collections.

So say I have a `forum collection`, `forum collection` has many `posts`, as well there is a `user` collection which has many `posts` (posts is shared between forum and user so that you can see a users profile and see their posts as well when you visit the forum it will populate recent posts)

What would be the way I should be associating these, should I directly insert the post into both User and Forum collection that way I can just query the user and get their posts, or should I store the posts in forums with a `userid` and then query the forum collection for posts by a certain `userid`

Sorry for poor formatting as I am on mobile. This isn't specific to a forum it is just an example on the proper way to be storing One-To-Many collections. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ask yourself why are you moving to MongoDB, MongoDB by definition is not a relational DB. If you want to achieve query performance, then the answer is to store the data twice and maintain it via code (when stuff are updated, update twice etc...).

If you don't have performance issues, consider keep it Mysql, cause holding relational data in MongoDB is less recommended since you don't really have transactions.

So there is no right or wrong, it's depends on what is the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I currently program as more of a hobby and mongo just seems like more my style of programming I guess if that makes sense I find MySQL can get quite convoluted with the queries and what not so I wanted to experiment with mongo

Comment: @Datsik If this is the case, try both, see the "price" you pay for denormalized data (double posts) and how mongodb works with relational data, both works, relational wasn't the purpose of this DB.